Joining 2 huge tables timing out
I have 2 tables with large data. The first one has 580 million rows and the second one has 1200 Million rows. I need to run a query where I join on 3 columns.
The 2nd table has multiple rows for the same join columns (with other columns being different).
The 2 tables have a non clustered index on the 3 join columns. I also have a filter to get 1 year at a time as the table has 5 years data.
SELECT det.Year,
    det.Claim_Nbr,
    det.Last_DOS,
    det.mbr_id AS Mbr_ID,
    diag.diag,
    diag.status
INTO #Temp_Table_1
FROM A det WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER LOOP JOIN B diag WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON det.Claim_Nbr = diag.claim_nbr
    AND det.mbr_id = diag.mbr_id
    AND det.Last_DOS = diag.last_dos 
WHERE det.YEAR = '2023'
    AND diag.last_dos >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00.000'
    AND diag.last_dos <= '2023-12-31 00:00:00.000'

Currently this keeps timing out after running for few hours. Is there any way to optimize this better without adding any more indexes? (as I do not own the tables)
The original query also has few other small temp tables that are being left joined to the above query to get some more columns. I tried to dissect the query into temp tables so that it executes faster.
Here is a screenshot of the query plan

Performance related questions require 1) Complete table definitions 2) Complete index definitions 3) The query plan - using Paste The Plan

Bad habits: putting nolock everywhere

Note I said "Paste The Plan" not a screenshot.

Note, databases have rows and columns, not records and fields. (You keep editing out my changes every time you edit the question. Please reload the question before you edit it).

With 20% of the table to read, an index won't be very helpful, I guess. Maybe you can partition the tables by year, so as to be able to work on a smaller base.

On a side note: AND diag.last_dos <= '2023-12-31 00:00:00.000' excludes the last day of the year, except for its very first millisecond. You probably want AND diag.last_dos < '2024-01-01 00:00:00.000'.

Yeah, after seeing you have heap tables, i kinda stopped reading. you don't seem to have index on the dates in the tables you're selecting from. You can perhaps create a indexed view, but it will be slow to create

Is there a specific reason you're telling the data engine to use a LOOP for the JOIN?

Will you have any cases where the det and diag rows can occur on different days? If so, you may be at risk at dropping data for such cases like det.YEAR = '2023' and diag.last_dos >= '2024-01-01 08:00:00'. Dropping the diag.last_dos filter and just using the ``det.YEAR` filter and join condition would fix this. (This is not an answer to the performance issue.)

@Srkuno - The reason we require that you use Paste the Plan instead of images, is that each step in the plan has many important details (rows read, bytes read, filter conditions applied, etc) that are not accessible with just a screen shot. Please upload your plan to the preceding link and then add the resulting link back to you question.

Try moving the predicate on diag.last_dos into the join ON clause.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

please remove the into clause when debugging.  You probably should first try without the loop join hint (why are you doing this at all on a > 1 billion row join?).  Later, you can try columnstores and batch mode to potentially help you go faster.  Using normal B+ tree modelling for what is effectively a fact table (in terms of size) is not optimal
